# error 403 en consola de desarrollador

Tags: reactjs, vscode

Estoy  haciendo un proyecto con Visual Studio Code con React, al hacer npm run dev me  sale este error en  la consola

content-scripts.js:2

```
   POST https://o438337.ingest.sentry.io/api/4506062147551232/envelope/?sentry_key=708a324f1a7ec87a2658346fb4bb7586&sentry_version=7&sentry_client=sentry.javascript.browser%2F7.75.1 403 (Forbidden)
```